# Real Linux instance vs WSL?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows 10 now has the subsystem for Linux available, I want to know what could be the difference between running a real Linux OS on a physical of Virtual machine VS running a WSL Linux instance?

Can I use WSL instance as a real production server or WSL is only for study purpose?

Is WSL Linux distribution less features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq):

> Also, even though you will be able to run many popular server applications (e.g. Redis), **we do not recommend WSL for hosting production services** – Microsoft offers a variety of solutions for running production Linux workloads in Azure, Hyper-V, and Docker.

(emphasis mine)

Also:

> [WSL] is primarily a tool for developers

Comment: It looks like they changed the docs July 2021 to remove the first quote. So... does that mean production services are not not recommended?